# HTML don't change text to email

Tags: html, perl, email, outlook

It's a bit complicated to explain my problem but I will try as good as I can.

So i'm writting a programm in perl that generates an email that i send like this:

```
system("mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -s \"".$subject."\" ".$addresses."  < ".$mailname);
```

In the mail I receive a text that looks like this "abc2@example.yn.swx"
Now outlook changes this to a mail adress.
Is it possible to write in the code that it shouldn^t change ?
I know I can change the options in outlook but this mail goes out to many people and I dont want everyone to change the options.

Thank you guys

Comment: If you're talking about the content of the email, changing the content_type to text/plain would solve this issue, but you will not be able to format anything

Comment: Might not actually - Outlook is remarkably annoying in terms of 'interpreting' things for you. `echo "me@me.com" | mail my_addr` causes outlook to interpolate.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook is magic, and it'll automatically do things like turn 'email addresses' and 'web addresses' into clickable links.

Doesn't matter if you send it plain text or not - it's happening client side so you have no control over it.

However, if you quote your 'email address-like' content, like so:

```
echo "'myemail@mydomain.com'" | mail ...
```

Then Outlook will show the (quoted) email address without automatically linkifying it.

More generally though - can I suggest rather than inlining a 'system' to send mail, you can actually do it a lot nice via an exec pipe:

```
open ( my $mailer, "|-", "/usr/lib/sendmail $mail_rcpt" ) or die $!;

print {$mailer} "From: My_automated_system\n";
print {$mailer} "To: Sobrique\n";   
print {$mailer} "Subject: Some subject here \n";
print {$mailer} "\n\n"; #end of headers

print {$mailer} $email_content;

close ( $mailer );
```